# Facebook Style Buttons with CSS

Tags: css, facebook, button, styling

I have a website I am looking to enhance with Facebook-style buttons, but I don't want to use the  tag to do so. I would be okay with an  if I could use CSS to style the buttons so that I had a result of Facebook-style buttons. Willing to use Javascript if the need arises. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is a very poorly asked question. What kind of buttons are you trying to create - the facebook embeddable "like" button, or the kind that are on Facebook's site itself?

Comment: Here's a basic example I put together. The image doesn't load in JSfiddle though, but works when on an actual page. http://jsfiddle.net/wfkPm/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is really easy with a border, a little padding and a `box-shadow: inset` property. There's a [JSFiddle demonstrating this here](http://jsfiddle.net/KDfux/1/). This uses no extra `div`s like Facebook does, although I wouldn't touch the Facebook source. Try ~7 nested elements for a single wall post.

Here's the CSS:

```
a {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background: #2A49A5;
    border: 1px solid #082783;
    box-shadow: 0 1px #4C6BC7 inset;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #082783;
    font: 12px Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

I've added a text shadow to give the impression of engraved text, but you can remove it. If you want to get the box and text shadow in IE, use [this project](http://css3pie.com/) to make things work.

Comment: very nice answer to a very poor question! +1

Comment: Thank you very much :-) I saw it and went "[my site](http://www.jamwaffles.co.uk) does that, and rather well!"

Comment: apologies, I don't do forums often. I was asking about the share buttons style. I will do what I can.

Comment: @Nicholas The share button is quite similar in design. I think the main points you need to take from my answer are `box-shadow` and a border colour a few shades darker than your `background-color`, giving a nice button effect.